# Android, Compose. How to correctly test animated scroll in compose?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I'm trying to test accompanist `PagerState`.

The author has already added tests (https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/pager/src/sharedTest/kotlin/com/google/accompanist/pager/PagerStateUnitTest.kt), however he uses `scrollToPage`, but I need to use `animateScrollToPage`.

But when i replace the `scrollToPage` with the `animateScrollToPage` (`change_pager_count` test) I get exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A MonotonicFrameClock is not
> available in this CoroutineContext. Callers should supply an
> appropriate MonotonicFrameClock using withContext.

I tried to remember coroutine scope and run `animateScrollToPage`  inside this scope:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
 scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
.....
}

composeTestRule.runOnIdle {
  scope.launch {
       pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page = 8)
      }
}



// And assert that currentPage and pageCount are correct
assertThat(pagerState.currentPage).isEqualTo(8)
assertThat(pagerState.pageCount).isEqualTo(10)
```

But I still get this exception.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.